# What's the best way to create a 2D Array Texture from a tileset image?

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk, opengl-3

I've been learning about OpenGL (3.3 Core) recently, today I tried to convert my Tilemap drawing from using Texture Atlas to using Array Texture. The main reason being it avoids bleeding between tiles.

It was pretty easy to implement and it works with my simple tileset image which is only 3 tiles placed vertically. However it breaks as soon as I tried a larger tileset image which has more than one tile per row, all I get is garbage.

The cause was quickly discovered: when there's only one tile per row in the tileset image, the pixels (rgba bytes) of a single tile is continuous. For example on 32x32 tiles, the first row of pixels is `pixel(1) - pixel(32)`, the second row is `pixel(33) - pixel(64)` and so on. However when there's more than one tile per row, `pixel(33) - pixel(64)` is no longer the second row of first tile, instead it's the first row of second tile. OpenGL can't create the correct textures because the pixels of a single tile are no longer continuous.

So I come up with the following code to manually create texture for each tile:

```c#
// Load pixel bytes
var data = bitmap.LockBits(
    new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb
);
byte[] pixels = new byte[data.Stride * data.Height];
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
bitmap.UnlockBits(data);

int bytes_per_tile_row = tile_width * 4;
int bytes_per_image_row = tiles_per_row * bytes_per_tile_row;

// Fill texture (one tile at a time)
byte[] tile_pixels = new byte[tile_width * tile_height * 4];
for (int y = 0; y < tiles_per_column; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < tiles_per_row; x++) {
        int index = x * bytes_per_tile_row + y * bytes_per_image_row * tile_height;
        for (int i = 0; i < tile_height; i++) {
            Array.Copy(pixels, index, tile_pixels, bytes_per_tile_row * i, bytes_per_tile_row);
            index += bytes_per_image_row;
        }
        GL.TexSubImage3D(TextureTarget.Texture2DArray, 0,
            0, 0, x + y * tiles_per_row,
            tile_width, tile_height, 1,
            PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, tile_pixels
        );
    }
}
```

This works but feels more like a workaround rather than a solution.
I wonder if there is a better way to solve this?

Comment: You could call glTexSubImage3D per line per tile, i.e. once for `pixels[0]` to `pixels[32]`, once for `pixels[33]` to `pixels[64]`. That might be quite slow though, depending on the driver… to be honest, you are probably best off just not storing your tiles with several per row.

Comment: Or, wait, perhaps you can do one line of a whole row at a time with glSubImage3D? If you set the width to the width of the tile, the height to 1, the depth to the number of tiles. Haven't tried that myself but this way you don't need to reorganise the data, I think.

Comment: @Andrea Wouldn't that only work for a image with only one very wide row? But I think you're right... I'm probably better off just convert the image to a very tall single column one ahead of time so I don't need to reorganize the data at run time.

Comment: I was thinking in either case you will need to call SubImage3D several times, which is unfortunate I guess :/

Comment: It is probably best to just convert it to one single column ahead of time, yes. You could make a small script to do it in, for example, Python, and put it into your build system/asset pipeline.